# Circuit question for LM358 and NE555

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-design, comparator, 555, astable

I have made an IR proximity sensor which works fine when an LED is connected.

[image: This is the IR receiver and emitter part of the circuit. The white LED is connected to ground via a 270 ohm resistor and is connected to pin 1 (the output) of the LM358]

*Figure 1: This is the IR receiver and emitter part of the circuit. The white LED is connected to ground via a 270 ohm resistor and is connected to pin 1 (the output) of the LM358*

I want to connect the output from pin 1 of the LM358 to an NE555 timer which is in astable mode (with a potentiometer) so the LED blinks whenever any object is near the IR sensor.

Could anyone please help me with setting up the NE555 timer in astable mode with a potentiometer?

[image: here the led lights up when the pencil is senses by the ir proximity sensor]

*Figure 2: Here the LED lights up when the pencil is sensed by the IR proximity sensor*

[image: IR sensor schematic, to connect to the NE555]

*Figure 3: IR sensor schematic, to connect to the NE555*

I have a 20 k potentiometer, please tell me how and what I need to connect to get a 1s or shorter time period for the blinking, whenever the IR sensor detects the proximity of an object.

Comment: If you want us to look at this, please include the **schematic**. There's a schematic entry tool when you **Edit** your question. A photo of a hand-drawn schematic is also OK.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie i have included the schematic , from the pinout 1 , i want to connect it to NE 555 timer in astable mode with potentiometer adjuster of resistance , how should i do it , and is it possible , so i can make blinking leds ?

Comment: Such a system will not work well as it will either have low sensitivity or suffer being activated by extraneous light.  For good results you need to use a receiver looking for switched light at say 38 kHz and if it is a repurposed remote control receiver rather than a proximity one, you'll also need to key that on and off at a slower rate to satisfy the AGC.

Comment: @ChrisStratton but it is working , i just wanna know how to connect its output yo ne555 for making blinking lights led ( astable mode of ne555 with potentiometer ) , the answer u have given is not relating to the problem mentioned by me .

Comment: I did not post an answer, but rather a caution about what you will experience if you continue this particular path further into the future.  You are of course free to continue to experiment with it.

Comment: Have you looked at the 555 datasheet showing astable mode connections?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany i have sir , but the problem is that , i need to make the astable mode work with the Vcc from the output of the LM358 comparator , how to do that , if anyone can give me a schematic

Comment: First, build a standard *astable oscillator* 555 circuit, choosing RC timing components for one second - get it working. Then play with pin 4 "not_reset" so that you can stop or allow the astable oscillation.